# How to make a link open multiple pages when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two (or more) links. For example: http://google.com and http://yahoo.com.

How can I make them *both* open when I click on a single link?

For example, a link entitled "click here" which, when clicked, will open two different blank windows.

Comment: I'd say these downvotes are probably because this behaviour will surprise most users - one click, one window is very much the norm.

Comment: Why blank windows? And why the silly link text of "click here"?

Comment: @Paddy: No, the downvotes are because the question is poorly stated.

Comment: Perhaps.  It's at least a straight-forward question I thought.  Perhaps -3 is a little harsh, given that this could be some kind of internal app or something where it's not a big deal/required.  Wonky, yes.  Worth burying to the ground with no explanation on the downvote?  No.

Comment: Yes, i see. But sometimes ppl needs to  show links in one click(specially at forums). It seems like hosting file links at mirrorcreator.com. Of course not same but similar.

Comment: paddy, the norm? excuse me but if you check off a bunch of of messages and click the [open selected items] link, it would be confusing and annoying if only the first one opened. Every time we shy away from multiple things because the bad people do it, we are acting like those things exist for abuse only, which is what is making HTML harder to write these days (frameset checking by sites, no iframes allowed, etc, the list goes on and on...) --- even more valid here at the end of 2015 though this is from 2011.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="yourlink">Click Here</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a.yourlink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('http://yoururl1.com');
    window.open('http://yoururl2.com');
});
```

`window.open` also can take additional parameters.  See them here: http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

You should also know that window.open is sometimes blocked by popup blockers and/or ad-filters.

Addition from Paul below: This approach also places a dependency on JavaScript being enabled.  Not typically a good idea, but sometimes necessary.

Comment: Also, if JavaScript is disabled then nothing will happen when the link is clicked on. It might be better to have the links in the HTML as normal, but with a class (like `yourlink`), then use jQuery to combine them into one link which opens all the URLs. That way you get to specify the URLs in the HTML, rather than in the JavaScript.

Comment: A sound approach, Paul.  Progressive Enhancement will save us all.

Comment: Awesome, Ben.  Be sure to mark it as the answer when you are able by clicking the checkbox on the left of the answer.

Comment: While this still works in Firefox, Chrome's pop-up blocker now blocks the second window.open (tested in Chrome 37 and FF 32). JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3p8tpvt/

Answer (score 24):

I did it in a simple way:

```
<a href="http://virtual-doctor.net" onclick="window.open('http://runningrss.com');
return true;">multiopen</a>
```

It'll open [runningrss](http://runningrss.com/) in a new window and [virtual-doctor](http://virtual-doctor.net/) in same window.

Comment: This one works for me. Thank you. One more thing: The window will be focussed on the onclick url at the end. :)

Answer (score 12):

You might want to arrange your HTML so that the user can still open all of the links even if JavaScript isn’t enabled. (We call this progressive enhancement.) If so, something like this might work well:

#### HTML

```
<ul class="yourlinks">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com/"></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/"></li>
</ul>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function() { // On DOM content ready...
    var urls = [];

    $('.yourlinks a').each(function() {
        urls.push(this.href); // Store the URLs from the links...
    });

    var multilink = $('<a href="#">Click here</a>'); // Create a new link...
    multilink.click(function() {
        for (var i in urls) {
            window.open(urls[i]); // ...that opens each stored link in its own window when clicked...
        }
    });

    $('.yourlinks').replaceWith(multilink); // ...and replace the original HTML links with the new link.
});
```

This code assumes you’ll only want to use one “multilink” like this per page. (I’ve also not tested it, so it’s probably riddled with errors.)

Comment: And assumes he'd want to use jQuery, although to be fair he has tagged it as jQuery. Good approach

Answer (score 7):

You can open multiple windows on single click... Try this..

```
<a href="http://--" 
     onclick=" window.open('http://--','','width=700,height=700'); 
               window.open('http://--','','width=700,height=500'); ..// add more"
               >Click Here</a>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unblock the pop up windows for your browser and the code could work.

> chrome://settings/contentExceptions#popups

[image: Chrome browser setting]

Answer (score 1):

I created a bit of a hybrid approach between Paul & Adam's approach:

The link that opens the array of links is already in the html. The jquery just creates the array of links and opens each one when the "open-all" button is clicked:

HTML:

```
<ul class="links">
<li><a href="http://www.google.com/"></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/"></a></li>
</ul>

<a id="open-all" href="#">OPEN ALL</a>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function() { // On DOM content ready...
    var hrefs = [];

    $('.links a').each(function() {
        hrefs.push(this.href); // Store the URLs from the links...
    });

    $('#open-all').click(function() {
        for (var i in hrefs) {
            window.open(hrefs[i]); // ...that opens each stored link in its own window when clicked...
        }
    });
});
```

You can check it out here:
https://jsfiddle.net/daveaseeman/vonob51n/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic implementation in javascript - I separated it into an external file

**HTML**

```
<a href="" id="multi-link-opener" onclick="openMultipleLinks(myLinks)">Click To Open Links</a>
```

**JS**

```
var myLinks = [
"https://google.com",
"https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp",
"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open"
]

function openMultipleLinks(links) {
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i ++) {
    window.open(links[i]);
  } 
}
```

Note that the user will have to enable pop-ups for the pages to open.

Here it is in action: https://jsfiddle.net/cuppajoeman/rjavuhcg/

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to inform the visitor which links will be opened, you can use a JS function reading links from an html element. You can even let the visitor write/modify the links as seen below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function open_all_links() {
        var x = document.getElementById('my_urls').value.split('\n');
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            if (x[i].indexOf('.') > 0)
            if (x[i].indexOf('://') < 0)
                window.open('http://' + x[i]);
            else
                window.open(x[i]);
    }
</script>



<form method="post" name="input" action=""> 
    <textarea id="my_urls" rows="4" placeholder="enter links in each row..."></textarea>
    <input value="open all now" type="button" onclick="open_all_links();">
</form>
```