# php download multi file in one click

Tags: php, mysql

I try to create a code to download multi file at once on one click

I use this code to read the name of the file from my database and take many file name in one variable using a href to page name download

**this is the code**

```
$file_query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_taskimage where db_taskid='$id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $src = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($file_query)>0){
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($file_query)){
    $src[]=$r['db_image'];}
    echo"<a href='download.php?src=".implode('/',$src)."'><img src='../img/download.png'></a>";
}
```

To dowload this file I use this code in download page

```
$src=$_GET['src'];echo $src;
$ex=explode("/",$src);
for($i=0;$i<count($ex);$i++){
$file_url = '../uploads_images/'.$ex[$i];
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
}
```

The problem is I can't download all the files. Only the first file will be downloaded. How can I solve this problem when I click the on a href all files will be downloaded?

Comment: zip files before download .... or use javascript eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451856/how-can-i-let-a-user-download-multiple-files-when-a-button-is-clicked

Comment: You can't initiate many responses at the same time. Create a single file archive for the user to download, or provide them the links to they can download them on their own.

Comment: the above comments are correct. The only way to do this is to put them all into a zip and then send the zip file to the client.