# Php download imagem using checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need to download a couple of images directly from my Website using Php and JS,
the user will select some of them by clicking into a checkbox and them click in a button named Download that will launch the action.
The html is showed below:

```
<div class="item-image">
  <input class="caixaSelecao" type="checkbox" name="image[1]" >
  <img id="1" class="thumbnail" src="<?= include_url('Im.jpg');?>" />
</div>
```

Comment: First you can do this by zipping all the files. Or using Javascript.

Comment: `include_url()` what does that do? That isn't a core php function, so if you're trying to run a JS method; it won't work. The question is way too unclear, and if you've no code, then this too broad since it looks like you're asking us how to do it all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the method of zip the images, use this example to begin

Example from [Download multiple files as a zip-file using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-a-zip-file-using-php)

zip:

```
$files = array('readme.txt', 'test.html', 'image.gif');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
```

and to stream it:

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

Using Jscript, use this example to begin.

Exemple from [How can I let a user download multiple files when a button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451856/how-can-i-let-a-user-download-multiple-files-when-a-button-is-clicked)

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="yourlink">Download</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a.yourlink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('mysite.com/file1');
    window.open('mysite.com/file2');
    window.open('mysite.com/file3');
});
```

Any doubt is just asking, that I will try to answer your doubts