# Call Trigger() in different lines not working - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, triggers

I have this function:

```js
function downloadAllReports() {
  $("#form\\:datatableReportAspectSpeed\\:btnDatatableReportAspectSpeed").trigger("click");
  $("#form\\:datatableReportAspectSpeed\\:btnDatatableReportAspectExcessDriving").trigger("click");
  $("#form\\:datatableReportAspectSpeed\\:btnDatatableReportAspectDailyHours").trigger("click");
  $("#form\\:datatableReportAspectSpeed\\:btnDatatableReportAspectRestrictedTime").trigger("click");
  $("#form\\:datatableReportAspectSpeed\\:btnDatatableReportAspectPreventiveDriving").trigger("click");
}
```

I call it from a link, the idea is that I want this function to click to 5 links i have. It just clicks the first one.

Comment: This is probably a security limitation of the browser to prevent malicious code opening multiple links. I'd suggest changing your logic to programmatically perform whatever action is required instead of faking events in the DOM.

Comment: r/limitation/feature :)

Comment: Rory is right. But, I am sure you can achieve this using window.location. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451856/how-can-i-let-a-user-download-multiple-files-when-a-button-is-clicked

Comment: @Rehmat you'll have the same problem there too, as the browser will stop you spamming new windows. You could potentially use `setTimeout()` to space out the calls, but that's a really hacky workaround.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Yes, the best and easiest solution will be to zip all the files, I mean if he is trying to give file downloads.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to download all these files (5 files), they come from 5 different datatables