# How to download multiple files in react

Tags: json, reactjs, download, h.264

I have search and found multiple question about it but every time when I try these responses I always download only one file or an alias.

I try a code to make download file (.h264 and .json), it seems work for some people:
- [Download multiple files with a single action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339440/download-multiple-files-with-a-single-action) 
- [How can I let a user download multiple files when a button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451856/how-can-i-let-a-user-download-multiple-files-when-a-button-is-clicked)

My last try is that:

```
function(uri, data, name) {
    let link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = 'data:'+data+';charset=utf-8;base64,'+uri;
    link.target = "blank_";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }
```

`uri` is the data of my file get before with axios.
`data` is the mime type.

This function is used here:

```
ListPath.forEach(path => {
    axios.all([axios.get(path+".h264"), axios.get(path+".json")]).then((data) => {
        console.log(data[0], data[1]);
        Utils.downloadFile(data[0].data, 'video/H264', "movie.h264");
        Utils.downloadFile(data[1].data, 'application/JSON', "data.json");
      }).catch(error => console.log(error))
})
```

And when I click to download one thing (one h264 and his json associated) it try to download only json and failed ("Network error") and redirect to `about:blank`. If I put in comment the json line it download nothing but redirect too.

I have also tried the method with `window.open()`, so code like this:

```
ListPath.forEach(path => {
    window.open(path+".h264", '_blank');
    window.open(path+".json", '_blank');
})
```

Here the h264 video is download, but it only give an alias of the real link (Like if we download our file on `http://mywebsite.com/data.json` and in the file it give one line with `http://mywebsite.com/data.json`) and for the json it was only display on other tab.

I'm using chrome under macOS for testing.

I've also try the `js-download-file` npm module but is the same issue than before.

Comment: Interesting, have you tried `setTimeOut` approach. Just curious. Make this function generic and independent enough and then see if you can fire it multiple times independently.

Comment: Yes I just tried it there is 2min, it works for my .h264 file but for json it's another way to get it. I just read that Chrome block multiple request. When you realise that was just simple.

Comment: You can make a function `handleDownload` and run this code multiple time, I have used it to download a pdf and excel file on single button click https://stackoverflow.com/a/54626214/9715289