# How to download file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, download

I want to be able to download a given file when pressing a button.The file will be provided via an `API` call.For now, I will have it in my local storage.
So my folder is something like :

```
rootFolder
-JS file
-HTML file
-download file (`sample.csv`)
```

How can I create a download `link`?
I have tried so far with :
`<a download="sample.csv"></a>`
I have also tried using an `onclick` event:

```
<a download="sample.csv" onclick="download()"></a>

function download|(){
   .....code that calls the `api`
}
```

I do not know how these 2 fit: `the download` API if there is one and the `click` event handler if you plan to do additional logic when downloading.

Comment: _“For now i will have it in my local storage”_ - do you actually mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage, or are you just talking about the file being located in the server file system at the place where you described?

Comment: The file is located in the server file system at the place i described.

Comment: Okay, so then you just need to do things correctly, and it should work … You still need to use the `href` attribute of the link to refer to the file; `download` is an extra attribute you add. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can provide the link to this function to download the file :

```
function downloadURI(uri, name) 
{
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    link.click();
}
```

Comment: And if the file is in my local storage it works all the same ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by local storage? aren't you using any local server ?

Comment: You can simplify the function in one line as:
`const downloadFile = (url, filename) => Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), { href: url, download: filename }).click();`

Comment: ONLY suitable where the amount of data is less than the maximum allowable URI length (~2000) [as explained by Paul Dixon's Jan 6, 2009 at 16:22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers/)

Comment: He probably meant: "What if the file is a blob"

Answer (score 19):

since the answer from @saibbyweb does not work in all browsers as I write this, i recommend an other but similar solution, tested and working in latest (as of writing) Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Edge, Safari, mobile Safari, mobile Chrome:

```
function downloadUrl(url){
    window.open(url, '_self');
}
```

Needless to say you could also open links in new Tabs with _blank instead of _self, but you potentially startle Popup-Blockers by opening new tabs/windows with Javascript.

Comment: is there a way to set a file name this way?

Comment: @Zoid Since this directly opens an url, only the server can send approriate Headers to set a filename for the download.

Comment: Use the [Content-Disposition header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) to set a file name (e.g., `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"`)

Comment: This might cause Session problems in mobile Safari Browsers, using window.open(url, '_parent'); resolved the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via HTML `<a href="/path/to/sample.csv"></a>`, but if you have to do it in JS there is https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ library.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Chrome's extension. You must have the download permission, in your "manifest.json". I put the code in the "browser_action" files, in the manifest.

```
chrome.downloads.download({url:"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626186/how-to-download-file-with-javascript"});
```