# How to generate a download file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I was stuck here not understood go further. some screens works same code but some not.

```
var element = document.createElement('a'); 
          element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(strOutput.replaceAll('£', '&#163;'))); 
          element.setAttribute('download',"fpversions"); 
          element.style.display = 'none'; 
          document.body.appendChild(element); 
          element.click(); 
          document.body.removeChild(element);
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download file with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626186/how-to-download-file-with-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is a sample javascript code on how to download files via javascript

```
  var textToSave = 'this is a test';
  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
  hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(textToSave);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.txt';
  hiddenElement.click();
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var textToSave = 'this is a test';
  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
  hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(textToSave);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.txt';
  hiddenElement.click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case using the idea of robin i put the next code for a url in base64
let url1 = `data:application/pdf;base64, ${response.data.c_planilla[0].PLANILLA}`
var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = url1;
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = 'Planilla ARI.pdf';
hiddenElement.click();

Comment: What is the different between your post and the one you are mentionning?