# Download files from array with url

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an array with URLs from checked checkboxes, after this I need to download all checked files on click

array look like `[url1,url2,url3]`

my script works fine, collecting data from checkboxes and I can show it but I can't do anything to download this files

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetSelected() {
    //Create an Array.
    var selected = new Array();

    //.
    var tbl = document.getElementById("acf-group_62bea885d8d59");

    //Reference all the CheckBoxes in Table.
    var chks = tbl.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

    // Loop and push the checked CheckBox value in Array.
    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
        if (chks[i].checked) {
            selected.push(chks[i].value);
        }
    }

    //Display the selected CheckBox values.
    if (selected.length > 0) {
        alert("Selected values: " + selected.join(","));
    }
};
</script>
```

I need to download selected file from ACF repeater field (file) in post.php
For now I can only download only one file but I need to bulk download selected
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boLZU.png)

Comment: I think this is the solution your looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626186/how-to-download-file-with-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download multiple files with a single action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339440/download-multiple-files-with-a-single-action)

Answer (score 2):

Solution to download files from a list of url :

```
const urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];

let fetchFile = function(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(res => res.blob());
}

let exportFile = function(file) {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.setAttribute('download', '');
    a.click();
}

for(const url of urls) {
    fetchFile(url).then(file => exportFile(file));
}
```