# Changing the page after downloading a file with browser in OnPost of Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages, documentformat

I am submitting a form in Razor Pages. OnPost method creates a MemoryStream and returns the data as a file. However after this, I would like to take the user to a page that says "Thank you for using this service to create your file". Since "Return File" is the very last thing the OnPost method does, I can not change the page after. Any help is appreciated.

```
public ActionResult OnPost()
{
  this.date = Request.Form["date"];
  this.name = Request.Form["name"];
  this.lastname = Request.Form["lastname"];

  string filename = "HelloWorld.docx";
  string contenttype = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";

  var stream = new MemoryStream();

  // **************************
  // Creating the document here 
  // **************************

  return File(stream, contenttype, filename);
}
```

The word document is created fine and downloaded without any problem. I can't change the page after though.Can I perhaps download the file without return, so that I can use "RedirectToPage" after?

I tried submitting the form to another page. However, the OnPost method of the other page is executed without actually displaying its front end. It just downloads the file from the back end of the other page.

Comment: One solution is to switch the order of the end user experience: 1. After successful validation of form data in the post request, redirect to the "thank you" page and then 2. Trigger the file download from the thank you page. This sequence is used by Microsoft, for example, when selecting a version of Visual Studio to download: Select the version to download [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads); the browser is directed to the "Thank you for downloading Visual Studio" and the file is downloaded after page load.

Comment: Note the text just after the "thank you" title: "Your download will start shortly. If your download does not begin, click here to retry." Use `TempData` to store validated form data between the `OnPost` and a custom 'OnGetFile` in the thank you Razor page.

Comment: Thank you. How can I trigger the file download from the thank you page? I mean without actually clicking a button there. Client-Side code to call a function after 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've expanded my comments in your original question with a full sample. This sample follows the sequence used by Microsoft.com when selecting a version of Visual Studio to download: Select the version to [download](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/); the browser is directed to the "Thank you for downloading Visual Studio" and the file is downloaded after page load.

1. After successful validation of form data in the post request, redirect to the "thank you" page from the `OnPost()` method of the Razor page with the form.

**Razor page with form named 'FormBeforeThankYou'**

[image]

.cshtml

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.FormBeforeThankYouModel
@{
}
<form method="post">
    <input type="email" name="emailaddress" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

.cshtml.cs

```
public class FormBeforeThankYouModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        string emailAddress = Request.Form["emailaddress"].ToString();
        
        // TempData reference:
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-8.0#tempdata
        TempData["ValidatedFormData"] = emailAddress;

        return RedirectToPage("ThankYouDownload");
    }
}
```

2. Trigger the file download from the thank you page. The file download is automatically downloaded by connecting to the `DOMContentLoaded` document event and executing `window.open(url, '_self');` in the event listener function. Note the format of the URL `"/ThankYouDownload?handler=Download";`. It's requesting the `OnGetDownload()` method.

**Razor page with "thank you" message and automatic file download named 'ThankYouDownload'**

[image]

.cshtml

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.ThankYouDownloadModel
@{
}
<h1>Thank You</h1>
<h3>Your file will download automatically.</h3>
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', downloadFile);

        function downloadFile() {
            const url = "/ThankYouDownload?handler=Download";
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626186/how-to-download-file-with-javascript/64874674#64874674
            window.open(url, '_self');
        }
    </script>
}
```

.cshtml.cs

```
public class ThankYouDownloadModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult OnGetDownload()
    {
        // Process data in TempData
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(TempData["ValidatedFormData"]);

        // Generate memory stream

        // Return generated stream as a file download
        return File("/assets/sample.txt", "text/plain", "sample-download.txt");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dave B for giving the idea to use two different pages. That helped. I did solve it a bit differently though.

In the first page I have created a parameter. If it is not set, it displays the form. Therefore, in the first access, it always displays the form.

Then when the submit button is clicked, OnPost saves the form data to TempData and sets the variable. This triggers the first page to display the thank you message instead of the form.

Then JavaScript redirects the URL to the second page which in OnGet method creates the word file and returns it.

```
<!--  1st Page Part - Thank You Message -->
@if (ViewData["message"] != null)
{
  Thank you message here 
  <script>
  window.location.href = "./PageToCreateFile";
  </script>
}

<!--  2nd Page Part - The Form -->
else
{
 form data filled here
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you worked out a solution. I've included a full sample of my comments.