# hrefs don't download files in loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have situation where I need to simulate several download requests on one button click. My code is here:

```javascript
download(filename: string) {
    console.log(filename);
    const href = <my href>;
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    a.href = href;
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
    a.remove();
  }

  downloadFiles(className) {
    for (let docLink of this.component.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName(className)) {
      docLink.click();
    }
  }
```

but the problem here is that file download is initiated only for one file instead of 3. What might be the problem?

Comment: What does this watch return? this.component.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName(className).length ?

Comment: it returns 3 elements

Comment: Try setting a `setTimeout` to delay the clicks.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451856/how-can-i-let-a-user-download-multiple-files-when-a-button-is-clicked

Comment: The problem is that once you click on the first download, the dialog opens for the user to pick where to save the file. While they're doing that, the other clicks are registering, but since there's already an open dialog, they are ignored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I let a user download multiple files when a button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451856/how-can-i-let-a-user-download-multiple-files-when-a-button-is-clicked)