# Download multiples files using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am trying to download multiple files from multiple URL's using javascript so far I have tried multiple options but it works only for 1 URL.

I have an array of URL's that needs to start multiple downloaded in the browser.

```
$(fileUrls).each(function(_index, fileUrl: any) {
  let tempElement: any;
  tempElement = document.createElement("A");
  tempElement.href = fileUrl;
  tempElement.download = fileUrl.substr(fileUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  document.body.appendChild(tempElement);
  tempElement.click();
  document.body.removeChild(tempElement);
});
```

Also tried using

```
$(fileUrls).each(function (_index, fileUrl: any) {
  window.location.href = fileUrl;
});
```

But it works for only 1 URL rest of the calls fails with below warning message in the browser

Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream

Answer (score 0):

> You can achieve this using below code.
>
> create one array and pass all the file locations which you want to
>   download like below.

```
var files= [
      'file1_Link',
      'file2_Link',
      'file3_Link'
    ];
```

> function to download all the files. we are creating the anchor tag
>   with download attribute and on loop we need to click on that link.
>   please see below ex.

```
    function downloadAll(files){
    if(files.length == 0) return;
    file = files.pop();
    var theAnchor = $('<a />')
        .attr('href', file[0]) // set index accordingly
        .attr('download',file[0]) // set index accordingly
        // Firefox does not fires click if the link is outside
        // the DOM
        .appendTo('body');

    theAnchor[0].click(); 
    theAnchor.remove();
    downloadAll(files);
}
```

// **call the function like below to achieve your goal**

```
downloadAll(files);
```

Comment: could you please create stackblitz of your issue. it will be helpful for fix your issue quickly.

Comment: or you can follow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451856/how-can-i-let-a-user-download-multiple-files-when-a-button-is-clicked . it might be solved your issue