# Download multiple files in Django without creating zip

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to download multiple files in Django **without creating zipfile** on single click/request. For downloading single file I am using the following code in views.py:

```html
def download_file(request):
   the_file = '/some/file/name.png'
   filename = os.path.basename(the_file)
   chunk_size = 8192
   response = StreamingHttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(the_file, 'rb'), chunk_size),
                           content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(the_file)[0])
   response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(the_file)    
   response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
   return response
```

Also the code should be capable of downloading large files in size of 100GB max as I am dealing with video files with high resolution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451856/how-can-i-let-a-user-download-multiple-files-when-a-button-is-clicked

Comment: The given code is unable to download the content.