# Apex - one buttons on same page, branching to different locations

Tags: oracle-apex

I have one submit button in apex application page. I need to create two pdf reports with one button press.

I have created  two branching for one button but only one branching  is working.

Then I tried creating one page process and one branching for the same button.
but only branching is working

```
 BEGIN

  htp.init;
        owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=&APP_ID.:0:&SESSION.'||':PRINT_REPORT=RepayORDShedLAy');
        apex_application.stop_apex_engine;

 end ;
```

How To solve this???

Comment: Could you use window.open(url); to invoke the two PDF reports, instead of submitting the page?

Comment: The solution Scott mentioned is covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451856/how-can-i-let-a-user-download-multiple-files-when-a-button-is-clicked Basically, it's request/response - not request/response-response. So, you can either bundle the PDFs into a single file (one PDF or a zip) or you can create multiple requests.