# Open multiple pages in once with javascript/ jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create elements which (when clicked) will guide visitors towards two differenct websites (both in new windows). How can I do this? Below are the two ways which I tried, which both do not work as only one page/ window is opened. Thanks in advance!

Timo

1. The solution as suggested here: [How to make a link open multiple pages when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064998/how-to-make-a-link-open-multiple-pages-when-clicked) . But maybe the solution is outdated, but for me only the first webpage is openend (with all the indicated solutions. (for example the code which is suggested there)

   `HTML <a href="#" class="yourlink">Click Here</a>`

   $('a.yourlink').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9XIXFwpyEc');
       window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=open+multiple+pages');
   });
2. While both using a class and an id with both a different a href and both with the extra options of opening new window also does not work as it only opens the first window

   `HTML <a href="#" class="yourlink" id="extra">Click Here</a>`

`$('.yourlink').html('<a href="url"></a>'); // Add page
$('.yourlink a').attr('target', '_blank');`// Make sure it opens in new window

`$('#extra').html('<a href="url"></a>'); // Add page
$('#extra a').attr('target', '_blank');`// Make sure it opens in new window

Comment: Your first example works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hc9nxanL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Chrome, I'm not seeing the problem you describe. But when I tested it in IE, I suddenly got a "popup blocked" message.

It's not strange though. I'd hate it if a single click on a link could suddenly spawn 10 new windows. In this scenario I actually think IE handles it better (by blocking the second window).

The thing is that `window.open` will only work if the action that invokes it is a *trusted event*. That usually means a user-initiated event, like `click`. But what Chrome doesn't account for (I assume) is that a single trusted event can then invoke several `window.open`.

I've tried to work around this feature, but have not (yet) been able to fool IE. The options, as I see it, are:

- Ask users to add your site to the popup exceptions (internet settings).
- Spawn the pages in iframes within your own site
- Ask users to use another browser ;)

Or the obvious:

- Use separate links for the windows

Comment: Thanks Mackan, the last options was my workaround option, so I am going to stick with that. Thanks for your helpt and the clear answer. It is not the solution which I hoped, but it is not a deal breaker. Thanks!