# Open multiple links with a single link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 sheet of csv in different .php file and they give an output with php://output.

when the user click a single link, i want to run multiple links.

I tried like this, but it ran the only last link:

```
<a onclick="$.csvIndir();" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">SAP Raporu</a>

$.csvIndir = function() {
    window.location.href = "finansuzmaniCSVRaporu_Nakit.php";
    window.location.href = "finansuzmaniCSVRaporu_Kredi-Karti.php";
    //window.location.href = "index.php";
}
```

Comment: how do you propose a browser displays multiple pages at once?

Comment: your logic is failing somehow

Comment: you want just open multiple links? Have you tried window.open ?

Comment: @JaromandaX so what is ur suggestion ? can i merge php://output s or must i use multiple links ?

Comment: it think this problem is already done by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064998/how-to-make-a-link-open-multiple-pages-when-clicked ?

Comment: you can maybe open more links in new tabs by using `window.open(url, '_blank')`, but not in a single window. This is not a good practice tho.

Comment: Use iframes to inject two different pages into a single document, or ajax requests to load them inside, or `window.open` to open two pages in two different pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `window.open`

like this:

```
window.open('http://example.com/', '_blank');
```

Note: user must allow pop-ups