# How to redirect two pages in one button click in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect, button

I need to redirect to two pages in one button click. Is it possible?
And this is what I tried. 
Using this code I can go to one page only.

```
 <form action="http://195.678.99.00:5002/predict" action="www.mywebsite.com" id="usrform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_blank">
<button id="myButton" type="submit" class="button button5"  >View pages</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the form tags, keep the button only:

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://195.678.99.00:5002/predict'); window.open('www.mywebsite.com');">View pages</button>
```

Be aware it won't work in all browsers because of popup blockers, as stated in the comments of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065030/4810180