# How can i redirect my all download links to a timer page automatically in blogger?

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

**Here see this blog it redirects automatically.**

**Download Page 1 :-** https://www.appmodders.xyz/2020/11/hotstar-premium-mod-apk.html?m=1

**Redirects Page 2 :-** `https://www.appmodders.xyz/p/download-app.html?name=Hotstar+Premium+Mod+Apk&size=38+MB&ver=11.2.8&link=https://www.mediafire.com/file/dzp1ucfrvo83iq9/Pure_APK_Blogger_theme.zip/file&image=https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/MmLkAp-x9OvA46_NgaD7dpXIsPkvb0OTJ-WlK_-7vyjZMjBMgJ0zHhsgg2NI3r0Lobc%3Dw800&m=1`

**Redirects Page 3 :-** `https://www.appmodders.xyz/p/thanks-for-visiting.html?link=https://www.mediafire.com/file/dzp1ucfrvo83iq9/Pure_APK_Blogger_theme.zip/file`

*I checked source code and got some js in download buttons*

Comment: You can try by opening them at once as in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064998/how-to-make-a-link-open-multiple-pages-when-clicked)

Answer (score -1):

you can use the  Base64 js for this. The script will automatically encrypt all links of your choice and you can set a download page say abc.blogspot.com/download.html where all the external links will go through.

What you'll need is;

1. Create a page where all download links will go through

After creating your download page, add the following code to the page by switching from "compose" to "HTML" view

```html
<div class='separator' style='text-align:center'> 
<div class='ads-top'> 
<!-- Put your Adsense code here --> 
</div>   
<div class='safelink' id='safelink'>  
<center>  
<div class='button outline' id='daplong'> Wait a minute...</div>  
<script>/*<![CDATA[*/ var currentURL=location.href; var str = currentURL; var res = str.replace('https://yourblog.blogspot.com/p/download.html' + '?url=', ""); function changeLink(){var decodedString = Base64.decode(res); window.open(decodedString,'_blank')}; document.write('<a href="#go-link" id="download-safelink" class="button outline">Click to get link</a>'); var linkDL = document.getElementById("download-safelink"); var notif = document.getElementById("daplong"); var waktu = 15; var teks_waktu = document.createElement("span"); linkDL.parentNode.replaceChild(teks_waktu, linkDL); var id; id = setInterval(function () { waktu--; if (waktu < 0) { teks_waktu.parentNode.replaceChild(linkDL, teks_waktu); clearInterval(id); notif.style.display = "none"; linkDL.style.display = "inline-block"; } else { teks_waktu.innerHTML = "The link will appear in " + waktu.toString() + " seconds"; }}, 1000); /*]]>*/</script></center> </div>   
<div class='separator-text'> 
<!-- Write Your Article Content Here --> 
</div>   
<div class='blockLink' style='text-align:center'>  
<div id='ads-left' class='ads-left'> 
<!-- Put your Adsense code here -->       
</div>   
<div id='go-link'> <a class='button' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='changeLink();' rel='nofollow noreferrer'>Go to Link</a>  
</div>   
<div id='ads-right' class='ads-right'> 
<!-- Put your Adsense code here -->     
</div>
</div>
```

In the above code, do not forget to change the link of the download page(https://yourblog.blogspot.com/download.html) to that of your own download page.

2. Style the download page

You can customize the download page using some CSS. Add the following CSS code before the closing head tag of your Blogger blog

```css
<style> 
  /* Safelink */ 
.button-outline{background-color: #086978;color:white; box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;width:responsive; border-radius:5px} 
.safelink span{display: block;font-size: 18px; color:red} 
.blockLink{display: flex;display: -webkit-flex;flex-wrap: wrap;-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;align-items: center;-webkit-align-items: center} 
.blockLink &gt; div{display: block;width: 35%;} 
.blockLink &gt; div#go-link{width: 30%;} 
.blockLink &gt; div#go-link a{display: none;margin: 0} 
.blockLink &gt; div#go-link:target a{display: inline-flex} 
.ads-top{margin: 0 0 20px 0;text-align: center} 
#HTML99,#HTML99 .widget-content{border: 0 !important;margin: 0 !important;padding: 0 !important} 
/* Responsive */ 
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){.blockLink &gt; div{width: 100% !important;margin: 0 0 15px;text-align: center}.blockLink &gt; div:last-child{margin: 0}} 
    </style>
```

3. Get the URLs, get them auto encrypted and replace their location

You will want only certain URLs to get encrypted and then redirected to your download page. First of all, add this JavaScript code to before the closing head tag of your Blogger theme

```js
<script>/*<![CDATA[*/ var uri = window.location.toString(); if (uri.indexOf("%3D","%3D") > 0) { var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("%3D")); window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);} var uri = window.location.toString(); if (uri.indexOf("%3D%3D","%3D%3D") > 0) { var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("%3D%3D")); window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);} var uri = window.location.toString(); if (uri.indexOf("&m=1","&m=1") > 0) { var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("&m=1")); window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri); } var uri = window.location.toString(); if (uri.indexOf("?m=1","?m=1") > 0) { var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?m=1")); window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);}; var protocol=window.location.protocol.replace(/\:/g,''); if(protocol=='http'){ var url=window.location.href.replace('http','https'); window.location.replace(url);} /*]]>*/</script>
```

Next, add the following JS code before the closing body tag

```js
<script>/*<![CDATA[*/ var Base64 = {_keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=", encode: function (input) {var output = ""; var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4; var i = 0; input = Base64._utf8_encode(input); while (i < input.length) {chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++); chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++); chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++); enc1 = chr1 >> 2; enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4); enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6); enc4 = chr3 & 63; if (isNaN(chr2)) {enc3 = enc4 = 64;} else if (isNaN(chr3)) {enc4 = 64;} output = output + this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);} return output; }, decode: function (input) {var output = ""; var chr1, chr2, chr3; var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4; var i = 0; input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, ""); while (i < input.length) {enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)); enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)); enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)); enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)); chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4); chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2); chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4; output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1); if (enc3 != 64) {output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);} if (enc4 != 64) {output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);} } output = Base64._utf8_decode(output); return output;}, _utf8_encode: function (string) {string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n"); var utftext = ""; for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {var c = string.charCodeAt(n); if (c < 128) {utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);} else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192); utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);} else {utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224); utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128); utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128); }} return utftext;}, _utf8_decode: function (utftext) {var string = ""; var i = 0; var c = c1 = c2 = 0; while (i < utftext.length) {c = utftext.charCodeAt(i); if (c < 128) {string += String.fromCharCode(c); i++;} else if ((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1); string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63)); i += 2;} else {c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1); c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 2); string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63)); i += 3;}} return string; }}; var encode = document.getElementById('encode'), decode = document.getElementById('decode'), output = document.getElementById('output'), input = document.getElementById('input'); var User_ID = ""; var protected_links = ""; var a_to_va = 0; var a_to_vb = 0; var a_to_vc = ""; function auto_safelink() {auto_safeconvert();}; function auto_safeconvert() {var a_to_vd = window.location.hostname; if (protected_links != "" && !protected_links.match(a_to_vd)) {protected_links += ", " + a_to_vd;} else if (protected_links == "") {protected_links = a_to_vd;} var a_to_ve = ""; var a_to_vf = new Array(); var a_to_vg = 0; a_to_ve = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); a_to_va = a_to_ve.length; a_to_vf = a_to_fa(); a_to_vg = a_to_vf.length; var a_to_vh = false; var j = 0; var daftarPostingan = [ "https://yourblog.blogspot.com/p/download.html" ]; var randomPostingan = daftarPostingan[Math.floor(Math.random()*daftarPostingan.length)]; var a_to_vi = ""; for (var i = 0; i < a_to_va; i++) {a_to_vh = false; j = 0; while (a_to_vh == false && j < a_to_vg) {a_to_vi = a_to_ve[i].href; if (a_to_vi.match(a_to_vf[j]) || !a_to_vi || !a_to_vi.match("https")) {a_to_vh = true;} j++; } if (a_to_vh == false) {var encryptedUrl = Base64.encode(a_to_vi); a_to_ve[i].href = randomPostingan + "?url=" + encryptedUrl; a_to_ve[i].rel = "nofollow noreferrer"; a_to_vb++; a_to_vc += i + ":::" + a_to_ve[i].href + "\n"; }} var a_to_vj = document.getElementById("anonyminized"); var a_to_vk = document.getElementById("found_links"); if (a_to_vj) {a_to_vj.innerHTML += a_to_vb;} if (a_to_vk) {a_to_vk.innerHTML += a_to_va;} }; function a_to_fa() {var a_to_vf = new Array(); protected_links = protected_links.replace(" ", ""); a_to_vf = protected_links.split(","); return a_to_vf; }; /*]]>*/</script> 
<script>/*<![CDATA[*/ protected_links = "javascript:;,blogger.com,paypal.me,whatsapp.com,youtube.com,telegram.me,google.com,twitter.com,pinterest.com,facebook.com,yourblog.blogspot.com";auto_safelink(); /*]]>*/</script> 
<!-- <b:if cond='data:blog.canonicalUrl == &quot;https://yourblog.blogspot.com/p/download.html&quot;'> <script>(function(s,u,z,p){s.src=u,s.setAttribute(&#39;data-zone&#39;,z),p.appendChild(s);})(document.createElement(&#39;script&#39;),&#39;https://iclickcdn.com/tag.min.js&#39;,3517783,document.body||document.documentElement)</script> </b:if> -->
```

In the above code, replace the URL(yourblog.blogspot.com/p/download.html) to that of the page you created earlier. You will find it twice.

Also, for the links you do not want to encrypt, your blog link should be one. Find and replace “yourblog.blogspot.com” with your blog link.

**Note:** The codes here were taken from one of my blogs *Blogger Customiz*. You can check the full article with a demo [here](https://www.bloggercustomiz.com/2020/11/how-to-make-automatic-redirect-download.html).